# PhoneGap/Cordova TabBar plugin and selected page

Tags: javascript, cordova, uitabbar

I have installed plugin TabBar for ios-like menu, and there is the method to put the selected page at the start of app.

```
plugins.tabBar.selectItem("home");
```

The problem is when i change tab its always selected "home", so i'm very begginer in javascript, and i tried with this code to solve it:

```
if(document.location.href == "index.html"){
     plugins.tabBar.selectItem("home");}
```

But it doesn't work.

Anybody know the solution?
Thanks people.

Comment: What actions/callbacks do you have when a tab bar item is selected ?

Comment: `plugins.tabBar.createItem("home", "Home", "/www/img/53-house.png", {
                                                        onSelect: function() {
                                                        location.href = "index.html"
                                                        }
                                                        })`

Answer (score 0):

I found this,

```
/**
 * Function to detect currently selected tab bar item
 * @see createItem
 * @see showItems
 */
TabBar.prototype.getSelectedItem = function() {
return this.selectedItem;
};
```